# jQuery appendTo serially as per DOM source order

Tags: jquery, append

I'm using JQuery to find certain div classes within DOM & If they found append them inside another div.

Here is working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gTAfe/1/

My code looks something like this :

```
var parentM = $('#module');
var eltofind = ["heading", "text", "image"];

for(var i=0; i < eltofind.length; i++){
     var thisElement = eltofind[i];

    if(parentM.find("." + thisElement).length != 0){

        var eltoget = parentM.find("." + thisElement);

        $(eltoget).each( function(index) {
                var count = (index +1);
                var getting = thisElement + "-" + count;
                $('<div></div>').appendTo('#output').addClass(getting).text(getting);

        });
    }
}
```

This script does append but it doesn't append div in the same order div classes are in the DOM due to each() function. Currently they are appending in the order `var eltofind = ["heading", "text", "image"];` are defined.

How do I remember current order of div classes I want to find & append them in the same order within each function ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are first finding all `heading`s, then all `text`s and then all `image`s.
So that changes the order. What you need is a multiselector. See: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

This will find all relevant elements at once and preserve order.

**This code snippet works as intended:**

```
var parentM = $('#module');
var eltofind = ["heading", "text", "image"];

var multiSelector = "";
for (var i = 0; i < eltofind.length - 1; i++) {
    multiSelector = multiSelector + "." + eltofind[i] + ", ";
}
multiSelector = multiSelector + "." + eltofind[eltofind.length - 1];

//this will contain all your elements
var eltoget = parentM.find(multiSelector);
$(eltoget).each(function(index) {
    $('<div></div>').appendTo('#output').hide().text($(this).text()).fadeIn(3000);
});​
```

Comment: Is it possible to set conditions for each before appending? I mean while heading append <h1>, while text append <p> & for image append <img src=""/> etc..

Comment: Try to use [switch statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) inside `.each()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's two options for you:

1)  The easiest just clones them and appends them.  It depends on how much control you want over each element though: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeschafe/gTAfe/3/)

2) This one gives you more control in code over each individual element if you want to make changes to each one or something: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeschafe/gTAfe/4/)

Comment: Thanks jeschafe ! I'll give a try both.

Comment: Is it possible to set conditions for each before appending? I mean while heading : append <h1>, while text : append <p> & for image append : <img src=""/>